# save JTable column data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, save

I'm passing values selected values from one table to selected row of the other.

```
int tableRow = table.getSelectedRow();
int tableColumn = table.getSelectedColumn();
int table_1Row = table_1.getSelectedRow();
int table_1Column = table_1.getSelectedColumn();
int table_2Row = table_2.getSelectedRow();
int table_2Column = table_2.getSelectedColumn();
if(tableRow > -1 && tableColumn > -1){
    Object obj = table.getValueAt(tableRow, tableColumn);
    jTable.setValueAt(obj, post, 4);
                    }
else if (table_1Row > -1 && table_1Column > -1){
    Object obj1 = table_1.getValueAt(table_1Row, table_1Column);
    jTable.setValueAt(obj1, post, 4);
                    }
else if (table_2Row > -1 && table_2Column > -1){
    Object obj2 = table_2.getValueAt(table_2Row, table_2Column);
    jTable.setValueAt(obj2, post, 4);
```

What I want now is to save all the values at column 4 of the second table.

```
int tableRow = table.getSelectedRow();
Object obj = panel.getTable().getModel().getValueAt(tableRow, 4);
panelEntity.setType((String) obj);
```

I could save the value but only of the selected row.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: `I could save the value but only of the selected row.` - that is because you code only saves the value of the selected row. If you want to save all the values then you need to create a `loop` to iterate through all the rows and save all the values.